# Trigger code when data entered in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I want this code to work only if I enter data on column AE.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("AE16:AE10000")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
            HideRuler (Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Range(Target.Address)`, you can write directly `target` in the `Intersect`. But beside this, code should work as required. However, you are calling a routine named `HideRuler`, the name suggests that this hides something, but you never call something like `ShowRuler`, so maybe that's your problem.

Comment: hi, thanks, but i found answer in other question, thanks to Santosh. i just need to enter "On Error Resume Next", and it`s work great

Comment: No, it doesn't. It still doesn't work like before, but now you don't know about it.

Comment: So what do you suggest I should be done to my code?

Comment: That depends on what this code should do. When `Worksheet_Change` is called, `Target` may be a single cell, or it may be a range. You decide what logic you want to have in handling that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (maybe depending on what HideRuler does)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("AE16:AE10000"), Target.Address)
    If rng Is nothing Then Exit Sub 'no cells to process
    
    'loop over all changed cells
    For Each c in rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then HideRuler c.Value
    End If
End Sub
```